# Wubi on Win XP - it starts, unpacks, but then ends

Tags: windows-xp

I try to start Wubi on and older Win XP PC. It starts (seen in task manager), unpacks the (some?) files and then ends...

Any idea how to start installation?

Kind regards - Chris

EDIT: Original post related to Windows Installer Download
Now Downloaded full Ubuntu 12.10 and starting Wubi from burnt ISO image: same result

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is a Q&A site, not a forum, and not necessarily a replacement for the Ubuntu forums (which can be found at ubuntuforums.org). You might want to check out the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for information on what's expected in this type of environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you're using Wubi? Depending on your purposes, it might be better to just go with the bootable installer.

That said, there are two things that may be stopping you:

1. Not enough RAM. Wubi prefers 256MB of RAM, but you can force it to run with less, though it doesn't like it and may not work at all.
2. Not enough hard drive space. Wubi needs at least 5GB of hard drive space free in order to be able to install Ubuntu. You can't get around this requirement.

Comment: Yes, I have no external drive, tried to create a bootable stick from win7, but it wasn't successful.
Both is present: enough ram and enough hd capacity...

Comment: Have you tried following [the Ubuntu site's tutorial](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) for a bootable USB drive? Additionally, you might want to try redownloading your Wubi stuff. It might have been a bad download.

Comment: Hi Shauna & thanks for the input. That's exactly how I got it to work today: created a bootable USB stick with wonderful "LiLi" - and all worked like a charm.
Thanks a lot for caring & kind regards - Christoph